# How to pass boolean attributes into Vue render function data object?

Tags: html, vue.js

The data object for Vue render functions takes HTML attributes and their arguments:

```
{
  // Same API as `v-bind:class`
  'class': {
    foo: true,
    bar: false
  },
  // Same API as `v-bind:style`
  style: {
    color: 'red',
    fontSize: '14px'
  },
...
```

How do you render an element that takes attributes that don't take arguments (there's probably a proper expression for this but I don't know it).  An example would be:

```
<f7-list accordion>
   <f7-list-item>
 ...
```

My attempt isn't working:

```
        render: function (createElement){
               return createElement('f7-list', {{'attrs': { 'accordion': true }}, 
                 this.tree.map(function(item){return createElement('f7-list-item', item.name)}))
```

How does one include these attributes?

Comment: Are you sure there there should be the double `{{`   in  ...`'f7-list', {{'attrs'`...?  Somehow that does not look right.

Comment: @skribe  It looks like attributes belong in a nested object to me: 
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth

Comment: Ok then see the edit I made in my answer below.  I still don't see where the second bracket is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass it as a prop and then use it? You can try like this I think.  (Untested)

```
render(createElement) {
    return createElement('f7-list', {
      props: {
        'attrs': {'accordion':true}
      }
    })
 }
```

Or perhaps simply

```
render(createElement) {
    return createElement('f7-list', {
      attrs: {
        'accordion': true
      }
    })
 }
```

Comment: Actually, I didn't need to put it in attrs after all.  It should go in props like this: props: {accordion: true}